# TypeError: curl.setopt is not a function]

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-libcurl

I am a newbie and trying to create an application based on poloniex.js API getting error-TypeError: curl.setopt is not a function] set node-curl(not working) and node-libcurl (partially works,but the function seems incorrectly expressed) slightly confused between the two curl) node-curl is outdated and maybe that's the problem-can you tell what is wrong?

```
    'use strict';

    var autobahn = require('autobahn'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    async = require('async'),
    https = require('https'),
    nonce = require('nonce')(),
    querystring = require('querystring'),
    Curl = require('node-libcurl').Curl,
    microtime = require('microtime'),
    events = require('events'),
    util = require('util');

    var Poloniex = function Poloniex() {};

    Poloniex._query_tradeApi = function (req, callback) {
    var post_data,
    hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', "key-key-key"),
    sign,
    received,
    headers;

    nonce = (new Date()).getTime() * 1000;
    post_data = querystring.stringify(req);
    hash.update(post_data);
    sign = hash.digest("hex");

    try {
    headers = [ 'Key: ' + "SECRET-SECRET-SECRET", 'Sign: ' + sign ];

    var curl = new Curl(),
    close = curl.close.bind( curl );
    curl.setopt('URL', 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi/');
    curl.setopt('POST', 1);
    curl.setopt('POSTFIELDS', post_data);
    curl.setopt('HTTPHEADER', headers);

    received = '';

    curl.on('data', function (chunk) {
        received += chunk;
        return chunk.length;
    });

    curl.on('header', function (chunk) {
        return chunk.length;
    });

    curl.on('error', curl.close.bind( curl ),function (e) {
        console.error('exchanges/poloniex', '_query_tradeApi', e, 
    req, e.stack);
        callback(e, undefined);
        curl.perform();
        curl.close();
    });

    curl.on('end', function () {
        try {

            var data = JSON.parse(received);
            callback(undefined, data);

        } catch (ex) {
            console.error('exchanges/poloniex', '_query_tradeApi', 
    ex,     req, ex.stack);
            callback(ex, received);
        }

        curl.close();
    });

    curl.perform();

    } catch (ee) {
    console.error('exchanges/poloniex', '_query_tradeApi', ee, 
    req,  ee.stack);
    callback(ee, received);
    }
    };
```

Comment: As hint discard curl and use Node.js Request module https://github.com/request/request to get or post data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax required is curl.setOpt, not curl.setopt.

Comment: yeah thanks..though did not see that there is a difference(

Comment: You are getting the same error message after you change it?  If so, that would be odd, and would indicate that you still have incorrect syntax when calling the method.

Comment: I meant that in the specifications curl.setOpt saw that requires exactly this syntax.This issue has been fixed. but apparently the code is too full of bugs..now I will check

Comment: If I answered the original question, please mark answered,